# Get the first 2 non-zero elements from every row of matrix

Tags: arrays, matrix, vectorization, octave

I have a matrix `A` like this:

```
A = [ 1 0 2 4; 2 3 1 0; 0 0 3 4 ]
```

`A` has only unique row elements except zero, and each row has at least 2 non-zero elements.

I want to create a new matrix `B` from `A`,where each row in `B` contains the first two non-zero elements of the corresponding row in `A`.

```
B = [ 1 2 ; 2 3 ; 3 4 ]
```

It is easy with loops but I need vectorized solution.

Comment: Is `A` guaranteed to have 2 nonzero elements in each row?

Comment: Why do you "Need a vectorised solution"? It's a common fallacy that loops in MATLAB are slow, especially since the JIT overhaul in R2016b. Please [edit] your post to show your code, a [mcve] in other words.

Comment: yes, it is exactly guarenteed @LuisMendo

Comment: I am using Octave and I need vectorized solution, this is small example code, In fact real matrix is huge...  @Adriaan

Comment: Still, that's no reason. Why do you need it vectorised? In case of large matrices loops might even be better, since you can do it piece-by-piece, not overflowing memory. Also, please don't tag spam. If you use Octave, then tag it as such, and not as MATLAB. The two are explicitly not the same, and solutions that work in one language aren't guaranteed to work in the other.

Comment: I added Octave tag, I think this question's answer is same for both of them.

Comment: To clarify: you want the _first_ values, not the largest, right? So maybe use `A = [1 0 2 4; 2 1 3 0; 0 0 3 4]` as a clearer example, and include the desired output for that

Comment: @Yilmazerhakan that's what I tried to tell you: there are things that work in MATLAB and don't in Octave. Yes, most solutions work in both, but not all the time (e.g. the non-unique `end` in Octave). So read the tag descriptions of [tag:matlab] and [tag:octave] and only use both tags when explicitly asking about differences or similarities between the two languages, and not when using either of the two languages. You restrict the answers to testing their code to work in both languages.

Comment: Yes, I want first non zero two elements for every row, order is important.

Comment: @Adriaan I need solution, now I dont have time for the differences of matlab and octave.

Comment: You time concerns are irrelevant to us, we are volunteers. If you need something done ASAP, hire a programmer. And as I have been trying to tell you in my previous comments here: **THERE ARE DIFFERENCES BETWEEN MATLAB AND OCTAVE**, whether you want them or not. If someone would've answered with a MATLAB solution that doesn't work for Octave, you're no better off. I'll step away now from this post.

Comment: @Yilmazerhakan Then please use an example that illustrates precisely that, like the one I suggested. In the one you use, "first" and "largest" coincide, which is very misleading

Comment: Why did you remove the `matrix` tag? It was prefectly suited. I'd also add `arrays`

Comment: @LuisMendo  I emphasized "first" non zero values in question, not the largest. So my A matrix or your example not important in the question. Thank you.

Comment: @Yilmazerhakan Examples _are_ important. That's why you included an example. But the example you chose is misleading as I tried to explain. Sorry, I'm downvoting because of badly chosen example. Let me know if you fix it so I can remove my downvote

Comment: @Adriaan I am phD student. So I am using Octave for free. And so I cant hire anyone. I tried 1.5 hours for the solution. And then decided to write here. So maybe question need some fixes. I dont need polemic in this time.

Comment: @LuisMendo I explained unique values in each row and get first two non zero values for every row. So Examples with the above conditions could change.

Comment: @Yilmazerhakan This was a nice problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a vectorized approach:

```
A = [1 0 2 4; 2 3 1 0; 0 0 3 4]; % example input
N = 2; % number of wanted nonzeros per row
[~, ind] = sort(~A, 2); % sort each row of A by the logical negation of its values.
% Get the indices of the sorting
ind = ind(:, 1:N); % keep first N columns
B = A((1:size(A,1)).' + (ind-1)*size(A,1)); % generate linear index and use into A
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible without using sort for the time complexity of the huge matrices.

Comment: I don't see how to do it without `sort` or loops, sorry

Answer (score 2):

Here is another vectorised approach.

```
A_bool = A > 0;   A_size = size(A);   A_rows = A_size(1);
A_boolsum = cumsum( A_bool, 2 ) .* A_bool;   % for each row, and at each column,
                                             % count how many nonzero instances
                                             % have occurred up to that column
                                             % (inclusive), and then 'zero' back
                                             % all original zero locations.

[~, ColumnsOfFirsts  ] = max( A_boolsum == 1, [], 2 );
[~, ColumnsOfSeconds ] = max( A_boolsum == 2, [], 2 );

LinearIndicesOfFirsts  = sub2ind( A_size, [1 : A_rows].', ColumnsOfFirsts  );
LinearIndicesOfSeconds = sub2ind( A_size, [1 : A_rows].', ColumnsOfSeconds );

Firsts  = A(LinearIndicesOfFirsts );
Seconds = A(LinearIndicesOfSeconds);

Result = horzcat( Firsts, Seconds )
% Result = 
%    1   2
%    2   3
%    3   4
```

---

<sub>PS. Matlab / Octave common subset compatible code.</sub>